# Twig fill array with last 14 month

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to fill an array with the last 14 month with twig.

**I tried**

```
{% for i in 14..0 %}
    {% if i > 0 %}
        {{ "now -"~i~" months"|date("M") }}<br/>
    {% else %}
        {{ "now"|date("M") }}* {{ i }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but that throws an error at this line `{{ "now -"~i~" months"|date("M") }}<br/>`

> Failed to parse time string ( months) at position 0 (m): The timezone could not be found in the database")

**This works**

`{{ 'now -15 months'|date("M") }}`

and dumping `i` gives me an integer (I think): [image]

Where am I wrong, is something like the above even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should surround with parentheses, as example:

```
{{ ("now -"~i~" months")|date("M") }}
```

So try this:

```
{% for i in 14..0 %}
    {% if i > 0 %}
        {{ "now"|date("M") }}* {{ i }}<br/>
    {% else %}
        {{ ("now -"~i~" months")|date("M") }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/ngjkz1) a working example.

Hope this help